# NodeJS / Express / Mean Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am new to Express and semi-new to nodejs and I am trying to run a simple app / webserver as a proof of concept. I have been stuck for hours because my server serves every file as index.html (with the content of index.html).

In my index.html I am making calls to JS files and CSS files and they are all coming back but with a 200 in the console but they are all coming back with index.html content instead of the actual content contained in them. I believe the problem is in my server.js file which is below:

```
// server.js

// modules =================================================
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');

// configuration ===========================================

// config files
var db = require('../config/db');

var port = process.env.PORT || 9999; // set our port
//mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our mongoDB database (uncomment after you enter in your own credentials in config/db.js)

app.configure(function() {
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location     /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.logger('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(express.bodyParser());                      // have the ability to pull information from html in POST
app.use(express.methodOverride());                  // have the ability to simulate DELETE and PUT
});

// routes ==================================================
require('../../app/routes')(app); // configure our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);                                                // startup our app at http://localhost:9999
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);           // shoutout to the user
exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
```

[image]

```
// app/routes.js

module.exports = function(app) {

// server routes ===========================================================
// handle things like api calls
// authentication routes

// sample api route
app.get('/api/nerds', function(req, res) {
    // use mongoose to get all nerds in the database
    Nerd.find(function(err, nerds) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(nerds); // return all nerds in JSON format
    });
});

// route to handle creating (app.post)
// route to handle delete (app.delete)

// frontend routes =========================================================
// route to handle all angular requests
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/Users/...../app/public/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
    //res.sendfile(path, {'root': '../'});
});
```

};

I have been following this tutorial verbatum: http://scotch.io/bar-talk/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application but haven't had much success.

Comment: Your server.js looks fine post your routes.js, and your directory structure would also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I've added my routes.js and my dir. structure

Comment: To clarify the issue is that the app isn't working at all. None of the javascript or css is loading, so no angularjs and no bootstrap. All JS and CSS is being returned to the browser as the index.html file.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot confirm without looking at your computer but I get the feeling the paths in your application are wrong.

The crucial parts in the express setup are:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

and

`app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/Users/...../app/public/index.html');`

The first rule catches and returns any static file in `__dirname + '/public'`.
The second returns `index.html` for anything else.

The problem is that your `server.js` is not in the apps directory (I can see this since you use `../../app/routes.js` to get to `routes.js`) this means `__dirname + '/public'` is not pointing to the public directory. Which is why your static files are being served by the global rule in `routes.js`.

In order to fix this change `__dirname + '/public'` to `../../app/public`, or better yet place your `server.js` file where it should be and update your paths.
I can also see you are using an absolute full path to `index.html` in `routes.js` instead of a relative one so it seems as if your applications needs to tidied out.

Comment: Thanks Eli, between your answer and AlexAtNet's comment on one of the other answers I got things working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial that you are following contains this route

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
});
```

which explicitly defines the behaviour you described.

In this tutorial it makes sense because it explains how to build a single page application. This type of the application typically returns the same content for all the request while the actual presentation work happens on the client by the client-side library (angular in this example).

So if you what to serve more pages with different content you need to add more routes for them, just like route for `/api/nerds` in the example.

**Update:**

After clarifying that the issue is incorrectly served CSS and JS files, the proposed solution is to check the location of the server.js - it should be in the folder together with the folder "public".

Comment: It isn't that I want to run different pages, I want the index page to work and it currently does not. Instead of loading my js/css files the browser thinks they all contain the same content as the index.html file so the browser throws syntax errors due to css/js file starting with a doctype.

Comment: Oh, I see - you need to check that the server.js and public are in the same folder.

Comment: you nailed it. Thanks so much. My folder structure was wrong and server.js had to be at the top level while everything served up needed to be in the public folder accept for my index.html page. The tutorial had a really bad view of the proposed folder structure.